# Codecademy 18/19 Battleship

Tags: python

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Let's play Battleship!"
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
print ship_row
print ship_col

# Everything from here on should go in your for loop!
# Be sure to indent four spaces!
for turn in range(4):
    print "Turn", turn + 1# Print (turn + 1) here!
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
        break
    else:
        if guess_row not in range(5) or guess_col not in range(5):
            print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
            print "You guessed that one already."
        else:
            print "You missed my battleship!"
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
            print_board(board)
    if turn == 3:
        print "Game Over"
```

I have some questions regarding this code:

1. When I input a number (`1`, `2`, `3`, etc.) on the board it shows as `2`, `3`, `4` accordingly. I want it to count from `1`, not from `0`; how do I do that?
2. If I just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it shows a mistake; how do I change that?
3. Could you tell me if there are some mistakes or if this code could be done more easily?

Comment: Creepy, I have rolled back to remove point 3 from your list of questions.  It's arguably outside the scope of Stack Overflow.  Once you get this code in working order, I'd invite you to post a working version to [codereview.se] to get some pointers on how to make it as good as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: `board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"` should be `board[guess_row-1][guess_col-1] = "X"`.

2: See below:

```
try:
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
except ValueError:
    print "Your gunners were asleep on the job!"
    if turn == 3:
        print "Game Over"
    continue
```

3: Instead of this:

```
board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)
```

Use a list comprehension:

```
board = [['O' for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]
```

And in Python 2 it's generally better to use `xrange` instead of `range`. Use `range` in Python 3.

Other than that, your code is pretty good and straightforward. :)

Here is the full code of the program. I don't have Python 2 installed, so I tested it in [`Skulpt`](http://www.skulpt.org) and it works perfectly.

```
from random import randint

board = [['O' for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Let's play Battleship!"
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
print ship_row
print ship_col

# Everything from here on should go in your for loop!
# Be sure to indent four spaces!
for turn in range(4):
    print "Turn", turn + 1# Print (turn + 1) here!
    try:
        guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
        guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
    except ValueError:
        print "Your gunners were asleep on the job!"
        if turn == 3:
            print "Game Over"
        continue
    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
        break
    else:
        if guess_row not in range(5) or guess_col not in range(5):
            print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
            print "You guessed that one already."
        else:
            print "You missed my battleship!"
            board[guess_row-1][guess_col-1] = "X"
            print_board(board)
    if turn == 3:
        print "Game Over"
```

Comment: it shows me:  File "python", line 32
    except ValueError:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

when i try to do what u did in "2"

Comment: Do you have all necessary closing parentheses on the previous line? Syntax errors often need more context.

Comment: could u put number 3 in a code, yes, i checked all the indentations, it still gives me an error

Comment: I have added the full code of the program to my answer. Please compare it carefully with the code you have to determine where the error is.